# Странные символы на выводе

Tags: python

При выводе доступных микрофонов выводит следующие каракули.

```
0 Microsoft Sound Mapper - Input
1 РњРёРєСЂРѕС„РѕРЅ (4- USB Audio Device)
2 Р“РѕР»РѕРІРЅРѕР№ С‚РµР»РµС„РѕРЅ (JBL TUNE600BT
3 РњРёРєСЂРѕС„РѕРЅ (e2eSoft iVCam)
```

код такой

```
import speech_recognition as sp
import pyaudio
mic= sp.Microphone()
list_mic =sp.Microphone.list_microphone_names()
for i in range(0,len(list_mic)):
    print(i,list_mic[i])
```

пробовал добавить в начало

```
# -*- coding: windows-1251 -*-
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
```

не помогло.

Comment: Что-то с настройкой вывода в консоль windows. Вроде, в последних версиях питона и винды все уже работает "из коробки". Какой у вас питон и винда?  Во всяком случае "внутри" программы результат кажется правильным.

Comment: Проверьте простенький русский `print('фыва')`, если он работает, авторы модуля 'забыли' про юникод, придется вручную перекодировать самому, или где-то в модуле исправить.

Comment: Да, вот какая версия то питона?

Comment: Использую PyCharm, Python 3.9 Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так, это должно сработать

```
import speech_recognition as sp

mic = sp.Microphone()
list_mic = sp.Microphone.list_microphone_names()
for i in range(0, len(list_mic)):
  print(i, list_mic[i].encode('cp1251').decode('utf-8'))
```